# Undefined index in PHP, same script in 2 files, same error

Tags: php, url, parameters

I have a bit of a problem in my PHP programming so I'll get to the deal.

This is the code that's bugging me:

```
$pageNum =  $_GET['page'];
      if(!isset($pageNum)) $pageNum=1;
```

Now, the idea is that instead you have 3 items on your page, trough PHP awesomeness, you have only 2 (from 3), 3rd being on another page, just as you have those page numbers on the bottom.

It constantly says:

> Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp2\htdocs\autosalon_db\model
>   Offer.php on line 3

(that one php file)

and the other one says this also:

> Notice: Undefined index: stranica in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\autosalon_db\index.php on line 10

(another file)

Now anyone can explain to me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please check `$_GET['page']` within the isset. You can use something such as `$pageNum = **default**; if (!isset($_GET['page'])) $pageNum = $_GET['page'];`.

Comment: @DaveChen Or even more simply `$pageNum = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the full code—or the URLs that trigger the code—so I will recode a snippet based on what you have provided. The problem here is you are assigning a variable based on `$_GET` before checking whether it exists. And you are checking if that variable is set afterwards.

```
$pageNum =  $_GET['page'];
      if(!isset($pageNum)) $pageNum=1;
```

Try this instead.

```
$pageNum = 1;
if (array_key_exists('page', $_GET) && !empty(trim($_GET['page']))) {
  $pageNum =  $_GET['page'];
}
```

What I am doing is setting a default for `$pageNum` before anything happens.  Then the `if` checks if the key `page` even exists in `$_GET` and if that value is empty or not. If it’s not empty, it will set `$pageNum` to be the value of `$_GET['page']`.

Should help a bit. But again, your question is missing some data needed for real assessment.